# Remote File Transfer from one linux machine to another linux machine

Tags: java, linux

Hi i want to write a java program in Linux machine which should read a file in another remote Linux machine and copy its contents to the source machine. I am using the following code for it

```
  JSch jsch = new JSch();
  Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
  session.setPassword(password);
  session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
  System.out.println("Establishing Connection...");
  session.connect();
  System.out.println("Connection established.");
  System.out.println("Crating SFTP Channel.");
  ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
  sftpChannel.connect();
  System.out.println("SFTP Channel created.");
  InputStream out = null; //.get(remoteFile);
  out = sftpChannel.get(pub);
  System.out.println("Read Successful");
  System.out.println(pub);
  StartString = pub.split("/");
  i=StartString.length;
  fileName =LocalWrite+StartString[i-1];
  System.out.println(fileName);   
  OutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileName));
  byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
  int len;
  while ((len = out.read(buf)) > 0) {
    fileOut.write(buf, 0, len);
  }
  System.out.println("Wrote Successfull");
  out.close();
  fileOut.close();
  sftpChannel.disconnect();
  session.disconnect();`
```

When i try this i am getting a fileNotFound Exception but when i try the same code in Windows Machine i am able to read the file and copy its contents to my local machine. Could you tell me where i am doing the mistake.

Comment: The line "InputStream out = null;" strikes me as a very poor choice of variable names, however it is not your problem.  What is the file name you are using?  I would be suspicious of upper/lower case problems.

Comment: Or you could call scp on the command line.

Comment: @AgilePro i have specified exactly the same file name as input.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey i dont want to use scp  on command line as it makes my program OS specific.

Comment: scp works the same on all OSes, but you have to assume it is installed and it might not be.

Comment: This code has debug statement. Care to include a sample of what they actually product?  StartString (is a variable) and it is not declared.  I am assuming a string array, but my real point is that the complete, compilable and runnable code is not included.  You are searching for a slash character, and that can be OS specific, but since no actual real sample values are given, we don't really know.  Make a complete compilable and runnable class and you might get some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell without more information. A wild guess (suggested in the comments): Did you use the correct pathname for the Linux system (which will be different to the name on Windows)? Did you pay attention to upper/lower case?

To debug this further, you could run `sshd` (the SSD daemon) in debug mode on the target Linux system. Then try to connect, and see what file name arrives on the target system, and why it does not find it.

Comment: Hi @sleske i made sure that all the naming conventions are same and file is available in the specified location. You have asked for more information could you suggest what more can i provide you to solve this isuue

Comment: Well, first try running sshd in debug mode, as I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Hi the problem has been solved. The two machines are in Different Networks hence the above code was not working.